# Wordpress, prepare a query with named params

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb

I am currently using wpdb->prepare() to prepare queries to be executed by wpdb methods such as $wpdb->get_results.

My query is built taking into account many conditions adding where clauses based on them, so using parameters like %s, %d is very inconvenient if not complicated.

I have prepared the following function to try to get around the problem but wonder if it is reinventing the wheel.

```
function prepare_query(string $query, array $params): string|bool {
  if (!preg_match_all('/{[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+}/', $query, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    return false;
  }
  $search = array();
  $replace = array();
  $args = array();
  foreach(array_pop($matches) as $match) {
    if (strlen($match) === 0) {
      continue;
    }
    $search[] = $match;
    $param = trim($match, '{}');
    if (!array_key_exists($param, $params)) {
      throw new Exception("Missing param $param");
    }
    $arg = $params[$param];
    $args[] = $arg;
    $type = gettype($arg);
    if ($type === 'string') {
      $replace[] = '%s';
    } else
    if ($type === 'integer') {
      $replace[] = '%d';
    }
  }
  $query = str_replace($search, $replace, $query);
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->prepare($query, $args);
  if ($result === null) {
    //echo json_encode($query);
    //echo json_encode($args);
    return false;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

An oversemplified example of my code can be:

```
$sql = 'select * from table where ';

if ($condition1 === true) {
  $sql .= ' field1 = {value1} ';
}
if ($condition2 === true) {
  $sql .= ' field2 = {value2} ';
}

$params = array(
    'value1' => 'value1',
    'value2' => 'value2');

$prepared_sql = prepare_query($sql, $params);
$wpdb->get_results($prepared_sql);
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I improve my way of doing things?

Obviously in my function I consider strings and integers, it is an initial sketch.

Comment: You can manually escape each variable using `esc_sql`. You can even write your own `prepare` function.

Comment: Function esc_sql is formerly an alias for escape and has now been deprecated. Also it takes care only of quoted params.

Comment: @PhaedraCasadio, the way you worded your comment confused me and I had to look it up. To be clear, the function `escape` is deprecated. The function `esc_sql` is valid and should be used.

Comment: When I need to do this I just use an array. Every time you add a `WHERE` clause, also note the parameter(s) for it. https://3v4l.org/ZMNOi

Comment: The problem is that so you don't handle parameter types, reuse of a parameter in multiple conditions, and you have to rewrite everything each time on a case-by-case basis.